# Spring Security 3.1.3 request querystring stripped

Tags: java, spring-security

I am securing my application using `Spring Security 3.1.3` and I have a requirement to allow users to login via a link in a third-party application.

However, the link in the third-party application will redirect to a specific resource and not to the login page, where the resource that the user wishes
to access will be defined as a querystring parameter. So, for example, the link would be of the form : 
`//server.com/app/build/panel.jsp?resourceid='blah'`

When a user clicks this link they should be taken to the login page defined in my Spring Security configuration and if authenticated then should be redirected 
to the original link including the querystring parameter. The querystring parameter has no influence on how the user should be authenticated it's 
merely an id of resource.

Now, this all works fine apart from the querystring, which gets stripped by Spring Security before it enters the request processing flow.

This is shown in the debug output from **Spring Security**;

> org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache: DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: 
>   DefaultSavedRequest[http://server.com:8080/app/build/panel.jsp]

ie, the querystring is not saved and `resourceid='blah'` has been removed.

Note, I'm currently using Ant matching. I have no need to actually match against the querystring.

In earlier versions of Spring Security, it seemed like you could influence this behaviour by using a BeanPostProcessor as per this post,
[Spring Security - Url with request parameters rules ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908052/spring-security-url-with-request-parameters-rules-ignored). But the method 
DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.setStripQueryStringFromUrls() has been removed from `Spring Security 3.1.3`.

How do I configure Spring Security to not strip the querystring from the original request? So that when the user is redirected after the login to 
the original `URL` the querystring parameter will be retained?

Many Thanks
Howard

Comment: I have debugged through the current release (3.2.3) and found the same thing. There's an enlightening comment in the javaDoc of the RequestWrapper: Parameters (as defined in RFC 2396 ) are stripped from the path segments of the servletPath and pathInfo values of the request. However, I also noticed that by the time the request gets to the wrapper, the container seems to have stripped them off (in my case Tomcat 7).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I'm running into the same issue with a RememberMe login.  I have a opt-out link in an email with two parameters.  It works if there is no RememberMe cookie or if the user is already logged in.  If there is a valid cookie and the user isn't logged in then the parameters get stripped before the request can be redirected after a successful RememberMe login.

Comment: From what I can remember the problem was down to having certain characters in the querystring. For this application I was dealing with a querystring which was received from an AngularJS frontend and that querystring also contained the AngularJS page navigation, which was represented by a #. So the querystring was something like //server/app/some-page?#new-issue/. It was the presence of # char which seemed to mean that the whole querystring was stripped. Do you have any special characters in your querystring?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The two parameters are encrypted strings that are passed through `Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString` - here's an example: `user/optout?id=t6A-cPHSUaB-oWYaZBqEhA&type=RQWAIAT1G_-TIzPbX2k4Hw`. It's an interesting possibility that I'll look into, although I've gotten really tired of debugging the Spring Security code to track down what sometimes seems as arbitrary actions on their part.

Comment: I found the problem - my fault, not Spring Security.  My custom `RememberMeSuccessHandler`was doing a redirect without the query string attached. The query string is definitely available by doing a `request.getQueryString()`.

Comment: @LWK69 could you add it as an answer so this question wouldn't hang around in the unanswered questions list?

Answer (score 1):

U can get it from SuccessHandler

**SecurityConfiguration class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
SuccessHandler getSuccessHandler;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()

    .antMatchers("/dashboard/**",               
            "/feedback/**"
            ).access("hasRole('ROLE_SYSTEM_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_COMPANY_ADMIN')")

    .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").successHandler(getSuccessHandler)
    .loginProcessingUrl("/login").usernameParameter("ssoId").passwordParameter("password")      
    .and().csrf()
    .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied")
    .and()
    .sessionManagement().invalidSessionUrl("/login").maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/login").and().sessionAuthenticationErrorUrl("/login").sessionFixation().migrateSession()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS); //always, IF_REQUIRED,never ,stateless    

    http.logout()
    .logoutUrl("/logout")
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
    .permitAll();
}

 @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
    .ignoring()     
    .antMatchers("/static/**")
    .antMatchers("/images/**");       
     }
}
```

**SuccessHandler class**

```
@Component
public class SuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {


@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
    Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/dashboard/index");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is basically the success handler.

You can take a look at this example:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/login*")
      .permitAll()
      .anyRequest()
      .authenticated()
      .and()
      .formLogin()
      .successHandler(new RefererAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
}
```

More info about it : http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-redirect-login

Comment: This question has been answered by the poster: coding error - see comments

Answer (score 0):

For others on a similar issue, refer  the link:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html

Extract:*There is a danger that when an application is deployed in a container which does not strip path parameters from these values, an attacker could add them to the requested URL in order to cause a pattern match to succeed or fail unexpectedly.*

However this stripping is meant to firmly protect the pattern matching for login. It doesnt means the query parameters are not available from the HTTP request, they should be.