# Spring's sec:intercept-url easily bypassed?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In our java app, we are using Spring security to handle role based authorization. Recently, we became aware that do to multiple servlet mappings in `web.xml` these URL checks were easily bypassed. However, after cutting it down to one servlet mapping, I'm still not sure we have our URL matchers set up right because they are ridiculously easy to bypass. For example:

```
 <sec:intercept-url pattern="/m/partner/list/**" access="hasRole('VIEW_ADMIN_PARTNER_LIST')"/>
```

At first glance, it does prevent a user with the role `VIEW_ADMIN_PARTNER_LIST` from loading that page... until I add `.html` to the end of it. Then it loads just fine. Or, if I add `.fff` or any other extension, it works. So, we changed the pattern to this:

```
 <sec:intercept-url pattern="/m/partner/list**" access="hasRole('VIEW_ADMIN_PARTNER_LIST')"/>
```

Which worked great! Now no matter what extension I add to the end of the url, I still get a 403 error. But.... adding a slash to the end of the URL bypasses the security completely. Not what we want.

So it seems that to truly implement actual URL pattern security, we have to implement both of those patterns? This is less than ideal, because we have over 75 URL security rules, and duplicating them and keeping them in sync would be difficult. Is there a better way to write the pattern matchings, or Spring's security inherently broken?

Edit: Here is the relevant info from our web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myproject</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/m/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Can we see the corresponding web.xml configuration? It's likely flawed that's why it's misbehaving.

Comment: @anttix just added it to my post.

Comment: At that point I would claim that there are other rules in your configuration that take precedence over this line under certain conditions.

Comment: Enable debug output with log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG, console to see which rules are matched.

Comment: Oh another guess. Maybe you have a line like this in your security config? <http use-expressions="true" path-type="regex"> 
If that's the case all patterns become regexes instead of ant matchers and something/** will only match something, something/, something//// etc
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908052/spring-security-url-with-request-parameters-rules-ignored

Comment: Now when I think about it, the behaviour you describe is expected if your configuration uses regex patterns.

Comment: @anttix, nope we don't use regex matching

Comment: Are you sure? What happens if you change the pattern to /m/partner/list.* ?

Comment: Definitely sure, the only thing that it denies access to then is the literal URL that ends in /m/partner/list.*

Comment: are you guessing or did you actually test it? It can be that spring security is accidentally configured to use regex paths and you just don't know about it.

Comment: YES. I actually tested it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to using regex expressions for expressing your URLs, it gives you more flexibility, for example:

```
<sec:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" path-type="regex">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/m/partner/list.*" access="hasRole('VIEW_ADMIN_PARTNER_LIST')"/>
</sec:http>
```

Notice `/**` was replaced by `.*` which in regular expression world will match anything.

Comment: @anttix - `What's wrong with ant expressions for his use case?` - ummm they don't work, as the question implies ;)

Comment: He is trying to secure a path /m/partner/list what is stopping an ant expression from working? Besides a notion that "regex is cool" ?

Comment: @anttix - the question was "Is there a better way to write the pattern matchings, or Spring's security inherently broken?" - that is exactly the answer I provided. Who said regex is cool? Do you have a better answer? What are you adding to the discussion?

Comment: @ike_lova his expressions are correct textbook examples thus there must be something else he is overlooking. Telling people to jump ship instead of finding out what's wrong with it isn't a solution.

Comment: It seems this is what we're going to have to switch to, because from what I understand about ANT matching, it doesn't match everything after the given pattern, especially if it is a `/`.

Comment: @RossHettel - hope it helps. Ran into same issues in my setup, never found a functional example using ant. The transition is pretty simple, you just replace URL ends that look like this `/**` with this `.*` and you good to go.

Comment: @ike_love thanks, sounds like you had the same issue we are having. I just did a test with regex matching, and it's not letting me bypass it like ANT does.

Comment: @RossHettel - excellent!  I have pretty extensive experience with Spring Security (including ACL), ping me if I can be of further assistance.

Answer (score -1):

Spring security uses Ant patterns by default. The pattern you are looking for is

```
/m/partner/list*/**
```

This will match

- /m/partner/list.html
- /m/partner/list/c.html
- /m/partner/list/c/d.html
- etc

Below is a snippet of Java code that can be used to test Ant patterns (add ant.jar to classpath)

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.types.selectors.SelectorUtils;
public class PatternTest {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println(SelectorUtils.matchPath("/a/b*/**", "/a/b"));
        System.out.println(SelectorUtils.matchPath("/a/b*/**", "/a/b.html"));
        System.out.println(SelectorUtils.matchPath("/a/b*/**", "/a/b/c.html"));
    }
}
```